# How Can I activate badges on un icon

Tags: c++, qt, notifications, bus

I have un Qt application who receives information from a BUS permanently.
I'm now asked when I minimize the application, to add information account on the icon of minimized application.
How can I do this with Qt ?
Kind regards,
Reza